# how to draw graphs for mobile application?

Tags: mobile, charts

I need to develop a mobile app (stand alone app.) for blackberry, android, iPhone and other devices. the app. is mainly to display various data using graphs (pie, bar, line and others). Please suggest me how to go about it? what language will help me or what API i need to use?

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Sencha](http://www.sencha.com/) framework and their ext.js library. It has functions to draw graphs.

Also there is a very good javascript library [protovis](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/) which can help you to draw visually interactive graphs